# Map/mapply with all possible combinations of two lists

Tags: r, apply, purrr, mapply

I am new to using R and apply and I am trying to download a set of .csv files from a website.

I want to download the years 2004 and 2005 (as an example; I want more years in fact) of three countries, Guatemala (GT), El Salvador (SV), and Honduras (HN).

I could run country by country something like this:

```
years = c(2004, 2005)    
Map(download.file, url = paste0("https://www.colef.mx/emif/datasets/basesdeDatos/sur/", years, "/DEUAGT%20S1%20", years, ".csv"), 
          destfile = paste0(raw_data, years, ".csv") )
```

This would get me Guatemalan databases for the years 2004 and 2005, as the Guatemalan bases are defined by *"DEAUGT"* in the URL. The Honduran and El Salvatorian databases are *"DEAUHN"* and *"DEAUSV"*, respectively.

But since I'm trying to learn, I wanted to make everything in "one run". So I tried:

```
countries = c("GT", "HN", "SV")
years = c(2004, 2005, 2007, 2009:2019)

Map(possibly(download.file, otherwise = NA), url = paste0("https://www.colef.mx/emif/datasets/basesdeDatos/sur/", years, "/DEUA", countries, "%20", years, ".csv"), 
              destfile = paste0(raw_data, countries, years,".csv"))
```

But instead of downloading the 6 files I wanted (three countries, two years), it downloaded 2 files.

Various posts I found here noted and in RStudio community noted that Map/mapply did not run through all possible combinations of the lists `"countries"` and `"years"`, and rather made point-wise (or something similar).

I found various suggestions in different settings but none particularly easy, and something tells me there is an easy solution for this. Using `expand.grid` creates a data frame and not a list of lists.

Comment: You would like to download from url of all possible combinations of `countries` and `years`?

Comment: Yes! But because of the URL of the file, I cannot make a list "GT2012, GT2013" and so on. I need something that loops through all years for one country, then repeats for the other, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the following solution. It is better if we use `purrr::walk2` in place of `purrr::map2` as we are calling `download.file` for its side effect, so `walk2` would is a better option:

```
library(purrr)

# First we create a data frame of all combinations of countries and years
comb <- expand.grid(countries, years)

# Then I wrap `download.file` with possibly for error handling
poss_download <- possibly(download.file, otherwise = NA)

# Then I apply our function on every combination of countries and years 
# in a row-wise operation

walk2(comb$Var1, comb$Var2, ~ {
  url = paste0("https://www.colef.mx/emif/datasets/basesdeDatos/sur/", .y, "/DEUA", .x, "%20", .y, ".csv")
  destfile = paste0(raw_data, .x, .y,".csv")
  poss_download(url, destfile)
})
```

Here is a base R solution for this question.

- Instead of `paste0` I used `sprintf` function which according to documentation "returns a character vector containing a formatted combination of text and variable values". I used `%d` for integer/numeric values(2 times for years) and `%s` for character strings (once for countries) and it should be noted that we have to provide as many variables so that they are incorporated in their places to form a single string of length one
- Then I used `tryCatch` in place of `purrr::possibly` to handle possible errors
- In the end I used `mapply` or `Map` to iterate on both vectors `url` and `destfile` at the same time

```
comb <- expand.grid(countries, years)

url <- sprintf("https://www.colef.mx/emif/datasets/basesdeDatos/sur/%d/DEUA%s%d.csv", comb$Var2, comb$Var1, comb$Var2)

destfile = paste0(raw_data, comb$Var1, comb$Var2,".csv")

mapply(function(x, y) {
  tryCatch(download.file(url, destfile),
           error = function(e) {
             NA
           })
}, url, destfile)
```

Comment: That does it! Thank you very much. There is a double comma inside paste0, but apart from that, it runs as it is. I really thought there would exist one function that just runs through every combination.

Comment: Glad it helped. I didn't notice that! where is it exactly? so that I can edit it. I will also present a base R solution. I noticed you used `possibly` thought you are familiar with `purrr` and went along with it.

Comment: In brackets: paste0(raw_data, {,} .x, .y,".csv")

Comment: @Anoushiravan. This is fantastic. You are my `purrr` man!!!

Comment: @jpugliese Thank you I edited and also add a base R solution.

Comment: @TarJae Thank you that's very kind of you. No come on! I just say the OP used `possibly` inside base R codes and decided to go with it lol.